# Creating javascript object without fieldname

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Hi I'm trying to create an object in JS which is like this
`{'0':{1,2,3,4},'1':{1,2,3,4}, '2':{1,2,3,4}}`
but I don't know how to create the {1,2,3,4} part.
These objects have to be created from something this :
`[{'value': '{1,2,3,4,5}', 'id': 0, 'type':'node'}]`
here is how I do it for the fieldname:

```
var domain={};
    nodes.forEach(function(node){
        if(node.type == "node")
            domain[node.id]= node.value;

    });
```

but node.value gives me String I don't want it to be string. I want to be in the form of {1,3,4.5}.

I appreciate any help

Comment: If not a string, what exactly do you expect the type to be for `{1,2,3,4}`? An array?

Comment: @Ian yea array but I don't want to use [ instead of {

Comment: That is not a valid object syntax. It's like saying you want to have some water without any H2O in it. You could have a string that shows `"{1, 2, 3, 4}"` instead.

Comment: @Amadan I'm sending this javacscript to python and in my python code I have something like this: CSP({'A':{1,2,3,4},'B':{1,2,3,4}, 'C':{1,2,3,4}},[ Constraint(('A','B'),lt)]) and it works in python

Comment: Then maybe change `node.value` to `JSON.parse(node.value.replace("{", "[").replace("}", "]"))`

Comment: "sending JavaScript to Python" makes no sense at all. You might be sending a *string* which looks like invalid JavaScript. JavaScript is a language, or colloquially a string well-formed in this language, which executes on a JavaScript engine. This will never execute, for two reasons: 1) it is not JavaScript, and 2) Python can only execute Python code. (BTW, `{1, 2, 3, 4}` is valid *Python* code for set literals.)

Comment: @Ian thanks it turned out just using an array like [] works in my python code but I used your Json.parse to make it an array.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a fundamental misunderstanding of Array syntax

Answer (score 0):

All properties of an object must have a name. However, you can use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instead (note that to be truly considered [JSON](http://www.json.org/), the property names must be double-quoted string literals):

```
var myObj = {
  "0": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  "1": [1, 2, 3, 4], 
  "2": [1, 2, 3, 4]
};
```

In fact the, whole object can be expressed as a 2-dimensional array:

```
var myObj = [ [1, 2, 3, 4],
              [1, 2, 3, 4], 
              [1, 2, 3, 4] ];
```

And you can access it's values like this:

```
myObj[1][2]; // 3
```